# Are there game configuration I can modify to set the graphical settings to higher than what is shown in the options UI?

Tags: source-engine, vampire-the-masquerade-bloodlines

In the options UI, I can only set the ff. graphical options (screenshots):

- [Video options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qufHr.jpg)
- [Visual options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Oc0F.jpg)

I learned that [Vampire: The Masquerade – Bloodlines uses the Source engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vampire:_The_Masquerade_%E2%80%93_Bloodlines). I reckon this makes it possible to set its graphical settings to higher than what is currently shown in its options UI, like [other games that use the Source engine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sX0wY.jpg).

**Are there game configuration I can modify to set the graphical settings to higher than what is shown in the options UI**, similar [to the video settings of other Source games](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sX0wY.jpg) (AA, AF, texture, shadow, shader detail, etc)? How do I configure that?

Note: I have installed the [**Unofficial Patch by Wesp5**](http://www.patches-scrolls.com/vampire_bloodlines.php) (currently v8.4.2), which already includes a custom resolution and widescreen patch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, it is **not likely that you will be able extend the graphics settings** beyond what you see available without resorting to [mods](http://www.moddb.com/games/vampire-the-masquerade-bloodlines/mods). Nothing noteworthy, at least, with the exception of changing the resolution (see below).

The reason why higher graphical settings are not readily available (without [mods](http://www.moddb.com/games/vampire-the-masquerade-bloodlines/mods)) is because the version of the Source Engine that Bloodlines was created with was a version that was **[Alpha](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vampire:_The_Masquerade_%E2%80%93_Bloodlines#Development_and_sales) or [early Beta](http://kb.speeddemosarchive.com/Vampire_The_Masquerade:_Bloodlines#Engine_Notes)** depending on who you cite. The developers of Bloodlines were also [laid off](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Troika_Games#History) shortly after Bloodlines' release, so they were unable to continue releasing patches. This also means that the game was never kept up to date with the latest Source Engine improvements.

Recap:

- Engine version older than the one that Half-Life 2 was originally released with in 2004.
- No developers to keep the game up to date for bug fixes or engine updates.
- Graphic settings are limited.

With [community/unofficial patch v8.4.2](http://www.patches-scrolls.com/vampire_bloodlines.php) or higher installed, **you can modify the screen resolution**, though. In my opinion, this adds the biggest graphical boost possible as far as any single change goes. Instructions follow:

**Step 1:** Install the patch! [community/unofficial patch v8.4.2 or higher](http://www.patches-scrolls.com/vampire_bloodlines.php)

**Step 2:** Find the `Extras` folder in your Bloodlines install directory (with patch installed).
`C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\vampire the masquerade - bloodlines\Extras`
[image: Step 2 - find directory]

**Step 3:** Find the ResPatch.exe program and run it.
[image: Step 3 - find ResPatch.exe]

**Step 4:** Navigate the patcher to the root of your Bloodlines install directory.
[image: Step 4 - find directory]

**Step 5:** Choose the [aspect ratio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect_ratio) (4:3, 16:9, 16:10 - most widescreen monitors are 16:9) that fits your monitor, and click <kbd>Patch It</kbd>.
You can click <kbd>Quit</kbd> afterwords.
[image: Step 5 - patch!]

Hope that helps you, or at least that it helps *someone* who needs the info!

Comment: This doesn't help me, since I've mentioned in my question that I've already installed the Unofficial Patch by Wesp5 (which includes the custom resolution/widescreen patch). It's a good answer, though (in that it could help someone else with a similar question).

Comment: @galacticninja It answers your question at the beginning and explains why. (answer = no, unless you install mods http://www.moddb.com/games/vampire-the-masquerade-bloodlines/mods) It then goes on to explain for anyone else how you can up the resolution in case someone else stumbles upon this question and is *not* familiar with the community patch. (I read your note before I answered and also figured that it was possible that you overlooked it's included widescreen patch)